# Dictionary comprehension for list with both 1 and 2 iterable elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to learn/understand Dictionary Comprehension and have the following list:

```
my_list = [ ['sam', '99912222'], 
          ['tom', '11122222'], 
          ['harry', '12299933'], 
          ['sam'], 
          ['edward'], 
          ['harry'] ]
```

This list contain elements with both 1 and 2 iterables, name and a number.

Using Dictionary Comprehension, how can I create the following dictionaries?

```
dic1 = {'sam':'99912222',
        'tom':'11122222',
        'harry' :'12299933',
        'sam':'',
        'edward':'',
        'harry':''}

dic2 = {'sam':'99912222',
        'tom':'11122222',
        'harry' :'12299933'}
```

If the list only contained iterables with two elements, this would work:

```
dic_all_iterables = {k:v for k,v in my_list}
```

I have attempted variants of the following with no luck:

```
dic2 = {k:v for k,v in my_list if not v is None}
#and
dic2 = {k:(v if not v is not none else '') for k,v in my_list}
#and
dic2 = {k:v for k,v in my_list if len(x)>1 in x for my_list}
```

But I can't seem to figure the correct syntax. Help?

Comment: For the `dic1` you can't have two same keys `sam` and `harry`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there:

```
dic2 = {x[0]:x[1] for x in my_list if len(x) == 2}
```

For dict1 is **not possible** to have a dictionary with **repeated keys**.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand you correctly, it's not possible to add just the name to the dictionary without a value?

Comment: @Doons You can add it with a default value, but the last one in the iteration will be the one valid.

Answer (score 2):

Something somewhat similar to dic1:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for lst in my_list:
    try:
        k, v = l
    except ValueError:
        k, = l
        v = ""
    finally:
        d[k].append(v)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'sam': ['99912222', ''],
             'tom': ['11122222'],
             'harry': ['12299933', ''],
             'edward': ['']})
```

Comment: Thanks! It handles the key duplicates! But it's not use of Dictionary Comprehension, so I'll note it down for later use